# Base of logarithm in runtime of Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

For Prim's and Kruskal's Algorithm there are many implementations which will give different running times. However suppose our implementation of Prim's algorithm has runtime $O(|E| + |V|\cdot \log(|V|))$ and Kruskals's algorithm has runtime $O(|E|\cdot \log(|V|))$.

What is the base of the $\log$?

Comment: It doesn't matter. When they are inside O-notation like this, all logarithms with constant base are equivalent.

Comment: That said, if you want to know which base the logarithm is before O-ing it away, you'd have to look/give us the specific implementation.

Comment: See also the question [Are log10(x) and log2(x) in the same big-O class of functions?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/are-log-10x-and-log-2x-in-the-same-big-o-class-of-functions/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on what David Eppstein said, you can assume it's in any base.

If the log were initially in base $b$, it is asymptotically the same as if it were in base $k$:

$$O(\log_b n) = O\left(\frac{\log_k n}{\log_k b}\right) = O(\log_k n)$$

because $k$ and $b$ are both constants; $\log_k b = O(1)$.

The logs in any two bases are the same in big-O notation.