# Complexity of a while loop that divides by parameter by three each iteration

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I've learned that a while loop such as

```
int i = 100;
while (i >= 1){
     ...
     ///Stuff
     i = i/2
}
```

will run in logarithmic time, specifically, `O(logn)`, since it keeps dividing in half each time (like a binary search).

However, what if my while loop looks like this

```
 int i = 100;
    while (i >= 1){
         ...
         ///Stuff
         i = i/3
    }
```

Is the complexity still `O(logn)`?

Can someone explain yes/no and why?

Comment: Yes, it will be $O(\log n)$, indeed it will be $O(\log_3 n)$, which is $O(\log n)$.  Recall that $\log_a n = c \log_b n$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: ...where $c=\log_a b$.  In fact, the time will also be $O(\log_{42} n)$, because the $O(\cdot)$ notation swallows the constant $\log_3 42$.

Comment: Pardon my math ignorance, but why is  $log_an=clog_bn$ for some constant c?  I mean, I just tested it with an example and it appears right, but I can't see why

Comment: See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/581/intuition-for-logarithmic-complexity/589#589) and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/base-of-logarithm-in-runtime-of-prims-and-kruskals-algorithms) and [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/are-log-10x-and-log-2x-in-the-same-big-o-class-of-functions/).

Comment: $n = b^{log_b n} = (a^{\log_a b})^{\log_b n} = a^{(\log_a b)(\log_b n)}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The number of times the loop is run, assuming it starts at $n$ and divides by $b$ each time, is exactly $\lfloor \log_b n \rfloor + 1$.